# why firewalls restrict the connection between two queue managers in message queuing whic are remote to each other

Tags: message, message-queue, ibm-mq, middleware

I was trying to connect two remote queue managers using IP address and port numbers. Actually one way connection established between the two queue managers but the two way connection is not established until i stopped firewalls. could any one let me know why firewalls block the connection.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean two way connection? If you mean two sender/receiver pairs (or equivalent) on going in each direction, then it sounds like one of the firewalls is blocking inbound connections whilst letting the outbound one connect. Basically MQ needs to be able to open a connection to the listener (or equivalent) and send data to be able to connect, and if that is being blocked you dont stand a chance. (Note the other thing to watch out for with firewalls are ones which drop unused connections after a while - make sure keepalive is on, and tune the heartbeat lower than the chop period!)